# How to bend the bendy bones found in Blender Builds recent to 2.78

Tags: rigging

I checked the Wiki, I checked the website of the original creator, I am still lost. Does anyone know how to make Bendy Bones Bend? I have added segments, I am not sure where to go next. Anyone know how? Please, I just want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess they bend already. Can you please verify that you are displaying them correctly? They only show up in BBone display mode:

[image: BBone mode]

Comment: B-Bone display, check. Segments, 9. Rotating and moving, not bending. I still seem to be missing a vital detail. Edit mode, not sure where else. Trying pose mode, too.

Okay, found it. Curve XY offsets, I am blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, I was not paying attention to every detail. Offset XY and settings next to it curve and bend the bones.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since you already added the segments to the B-Bone, you can use the bendy bone functions under the bone tab. there are some useful tools if you are sure staying in the B-Bone shown mode, In X, Out X, In Y, Out Y, etc...
and use that with keying frames you are gonna see how amazing it will be. :P 
have fun!

Comment: An image showing exactly where the settings you mention are could be useful.